# How can I convert an apk to html?

Tags: html, apk

**I create APK in MIT App website**

> I want , my APK convert to html for I can use APK and website

What should I do ???

Comment: can you explain your question properly? what actually you are looking for.

Comment: An APK and a website are two very different application formats. It sounds like you're looking for a tool that converts an Android application into a website application? That's probably not a good idea to begin with. But that aside, this question is effectively asking for a tool to do that conversion—which is off topic for Stack Overflow. (The alternative is you rewrite the functionality as a web app.)